# I want to create a hero image with text and a button on my front page. How can I do this?

Tags: images

I want to create a hero image with text and a button on my front page. How can I do this? Here is a example of what I mean. [image: Hero image example]

Answer (score 0):

You just need a plugin or a good builder.

You can use the following plugin:
http://www.slider-hero.com/

or use a builder by themify.
https://themify.me/builder

Both will do the trick.